# Xcode 6 autolayout portrait only

Tags: rotation, autolayout, constraints, xcode6, portrait

how to build app on portrait mode only for all devices with using autolayout ?

When i put the device in landscape mode 
all elements rotate with the device how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had set my app in Portrait mode by using below steps :

1. Select your `project` from `Navigator` window
2. Select `target` from `TARGETS section`
3. Select `General` tab from list of tab on top
4. Goto `Deployment Info` drop-down. Open it if closed.
5. `Check only Portrait` from Device Orientation list.

[image: Screenshot for steps]

Answer (score 2):

In your .plist you can also change this Setting, maybe you have Landscape added in there?

Answer (score 1):

what about adjusting settings in xcode app settings? Have you tryed it?
[image]